# Use login from another database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, authentication

I'm using Entity Framework for the login but I have another login already registered and I want to use those logins to access my page. I tried to change the db connection (it was for the default: `defaultConnection`) to my db connection. The table is exactly the same as the `DefaultConnection` but I can't login with those users already registered.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("ResourceManager", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're using asp.net identity for your authentication provider. You're telling it to use ResourceManager connection. Do all of the tables for asp.net identity exist  exactly like the ones in the db for defaultconnection? Is this from another site? If so, is/was it using the same version of asp.net identity? What errors are you receiving?

Comment: yes the tables are exactly the same, just instead of email+password to login i changed to username+password.

Comment: http://s1.postimg.org/q25zl2ymn/erro2.png 

"Error related to the network or the specific instance when establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server / Instance Specified)"

Comment: That looks like a connection string problem, not an authentication problem (That may come next once you connect).

Comment: Once you get the connection fixed, you should lookup logging in to asp.net identity with username instead of email. You will likely need to lookup the user by username and then pass the associated email to PasswordSigninAsync.